# Using a `let` binding to increase a values lifetime

Tags: rust, lifetime, let

I wrote the following code to read an array of integers from `stdin`:

```
use std::io::{self, BufRead};

fn main() {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    for line in stdin.lock().lines() {
        let xs: Vec<i32> = line.unwrap()
            .trim()
            .split(' ')
            .map(|s| s.parse().unwrap())
            .collect();

        println!("{:?}", xs);
    }
}
```

This worked fine, however, I felt the `let xs` line was a bit long, so I split it into two:

```
use std::io::{self, BufRead};

fn main() {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    for line in stdin.lock().lines() {
        let ss = line.unwrap().trim().split(' ');
        let xs: Vec<i32> = ss.map(|s| s.parse().unwrap()).collect();

        println!("{:?}", xs);
    }
}
```

This didn't work! Rust replied with the following error:

```
error[E0597]: borrowed value does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:6:18
   |
6  |         let ss = line.unwrap().trim().split(' ');
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^                  - temporary value dropped here while still borrowed
   |                  |
   |                  temporary value does not live long enough
...
10 |     }
   |     - temporary value needs to live until here
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to increase its lifetime
```

This confuses me. Is it `line` or `ss` that doesn't live long enough? And how can I use a `let` binding to increase their lifetime? I thought I was already using a `let`?

I've read through the [lifetime guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20141018182346/http://doc.rust-lang.org/guide-lifetimes.html), but I still can't quite figure it out. Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In your second version, the type of `ss` is [`Split<'a, char>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Split.html). The lifetime parameter in the type tells us that the object contains a reference. In order for the assignment to be valid, the reference must point to an object that exists after that statement. However, [`unwrap()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap) consumes `line`; in other words, it moves `Ok` variant's data out of the `Result` object. Therefore, the reference doesn't point inside the original `line`, but rather on a temporary object.

In your first version, you consume the temporary by the end of the long expression, though the call to `map`. To fix your second version, you need to bind the result of `unwrap()` to keep the value living long enough:

```
use std::io::{self, BufRead};

fn main() {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    for line in stdin.lock().lines() {
        let line = line.unwrap();
        let ss = line.trim().split(' ');
        let xs: Vec<i32> = ss.map(|s| s.parse().unwrap()).collect();

        println!("{:?}", xs);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand you correctly, `CharSplits` references the value inside `line`. But actually it references a copy taken from `Ok`, which is thrown away as soon as the `let ss` line ends. Instead of just keeping all values alive till the end of the block?

Comment: Yes. Temporary values are only valid for the statement in which the expression that produces that value is located.

Comment: Watch out, there are 2 variables named `line` here: the first one is an `IoResult<String>` (= `Result<String, IoError>`), the second is a `String`. `unwrap()` *moves* the `String` out of the `IoResult`, and the `IoResult` is unusable after that (which is also why I'm reusing the name `line`: you wouldn't be able to use the first `line` anyway). The `String` is not copied at all.

Comment: That's very interesting. How is a move like that done? Is the data copied and the original destroyed? Or was the String on heap and the original pointer to it was destroyed?

Comment: A `String` struct contains a `Vec`, which contains a pointer to the data (stored on the heap), a length and a capacity. When a move occurs, the struct's members are copied, but the referenced data is not copied and no destructor is run. The original copy is then made unusable by the compiler (you'll get an error if you try to use the value) so you don't access data whose ownership has been transferred.

Answer (score 7):

It's about the `unwrap()` call, it's getting the contained object but this reference should outlive the container object, which goes out of scope in the next line (there is no local binding to it).

If you want to get cleaner code, a very common way to write it is:

```
use std::io::{self, BufRead};

fn main() {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    for line in stdin.lock().lines() {
        let xs: Vec<i32> = line.unwrap()
            .trim()
            .split(' ')
            .map(|s| s.parse().unwrap())
            .collect();

        println!("{:?}", xs);
    }
}
```

If not, you can create the binding to the "unwrapped" result and use it.

Comment: So you are saying that the `line` is out of scope in the `let xs` line, but not in the `let ss` line, even though they are in the same block?

Comment: It's the `line.unwrap()` result that goes out of scope.

Comment: Thank you I think I'm starting to get it.