# Why does the compiler tell me to consider using a `let` binding" when I already am?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

What is my error and how to fix it?

```
fn get_m() -> Vec<i8> {
    vec![1, 2, 3]
}

fn main() {
    let mut vals = get_m().iter().peekable();
    println!("Saw a {:?}", vals.peek());
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ef5d900909a0e1e64161cef57088e47e&version=stable))

The compiler's error suggests "consider using a `let` binding" — but I already am:

```
error[E0597]: borrowed value does not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:6:45
  |
6 |     let mut vals = get_m().iter().peekable();
  |                    -------                  ^ temporary value dropped here while still borrowed
  |                    |
  |                    temporary value created here
7 |     println!("Saw a {:?}", vals.peek());
8 | }
  | - temporary value needs to live until here
  |
  = note: consider using a `let` binding to increase its lifetime
```

This is obviously a newbie question -- though I thought I'd written enough Rust at this point that I had a handle on the borrow checker... apparently I haven't.

This question is similar to [Using a `let` binding to increase value lifetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26080157/using-a-let-binding-to-increase-value-lifetime?rq=1), but doesn't involve breaking down an expression into multiple statements, so I don't think the problem is identical.

Comment: A hint on reading the error messages: “borrowed value does not live long enough”. Which borrowed value? Look at the span, it’s `get_m()`. “Consider using a let binding to increase its lifetime”. That is, use a let binding *on the `get_m()` part*.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisMorgan! The extent of the squiggles is a nice clue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that the `Peekable` iterator lives to the end of the function, but it holds a reference to the vector returned by `get_m`, which only lasts as long as the statement containing that call.

There are actually a lot of things going on here, so let's take it step by step:

- `get_m` allocates and returns a vector, of type `Vec<i8>`.
- We make the call `.iter()`. Surprisingly, `Vec<i8>` has no `iter` method, nor does it implement any trait that has one. So there are three sub-steps here:

  - Any method call checks whether its `self` value implements the `Deref` trait, and applies it if necessary. `Vec<i8>` does implement `Deref`, so we implicitly call its `deref` method. However, `deref` takes its `self` argument by reference, which means that `get_m()` is now an rvalue appearing in an lvalue context. In this situation, Rust creates a temporary to hold the value, and passes a reference to that. (Keep an eye on this temporary!)
  - We call `deref`, yielding a slice of type `&[i8]` borrowing the vector's elements.
  - This slice implements the `SliceExt` trait, which *does* have an `iter` method. Finally! This `iter` also takes its `self` argument by reference, and returns a `std::slice::Iter` holding a reference to the slice.
- We make the call `.peekable()`. As before, `std::slice::Iter` has no `peekable` method, but it does implement `Iterator`; `IteratorExt` is implemented for every `Iterator`; and `IteratorExt` *does* have a `peekable` method. This takes its `self` by value, so the `Iter` is consumed, and we get a `std::iter::Peekable` back in return, again holding a reference to the slice.
- This `Peekable` is then bound to the variable `vals`, which lives to the end of the function.
- The temporary holding the original `Vec<i8>`, to whose elements the `Peekable` refers, now dies. Oops. This is the borrowed value not living long enough.

But the temporary dies there only because that's the rule for temporaries. If we give it a name, then it lasts as long as its name is in scope:

```
let vec = get_m();
let mut peekable = vec.iter().peekable();
println!("Saw a {:?}", vals.peek());
```

I think that's the story. What still confuses me, though, is why that temporary doesn't live longer, even without a name. The Rust reference says, "A temporary's lifetime equals the largest lifetime of any reference that points to it." But that's clearly not the case here.

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to dig in here! Quick question: where can I go to learn things like "Any method call checks whether its self value implements the Deref trait, and applies it if necessary."? I mean, the language specs are one source; but is there anything higher-level?

Comment: Well, I got it from reading the Rust reference: http://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html See especially the section on "field expressions". But that's not really very clear; I'm told the reference is due for a major refresh soon. The other source is the docs for the Deref trait itself: http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html But that's not great either. I do a lot of experimentation.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the best reference for the temporary lifetime rules, but certainly that quote from the reference is incorrect. This blog post covers a lot of the reasoning that went into the current rule, but I don't think it's fully up to date with the rule as implemented: http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2014/01/09/rvalue-lifetimes-in-rust/ Hopefully, we'll update the reference soon (note also that there is an accepted, but unimplemented, RFC that tweaks the rules in some cases, #66)

Answer (score 6):

This is happening because you are trying to run your `.iter().peekable()` on the actual vector inside of `get_m()`, which is getting re-referenced by `vals`.

Basically, you want something like this:

```
fn get_m() -> Vec<i8> {
    vec![1, 2, 3]
}

fn main() {
    let vals = get_m();
    let mut val = vals.iter().peekable();
    println!("Saw a {:?}", val.peek());
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0a6628aa1ac9ac5689e3e8aecb67c278&version=stable))

Result:

```
Saw a Some(1)
```