# error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed

Tags: rust

I have a function which receive some parameter, but when I try to use the parameter, it throw an error.

// the function

```rust
pub fn solc_compile(compiler: &str, file: &str, out: &str, config: templates::Config) {
    let mut args = vec![
        "--bin",
        "--abi",
        "--include-path",
        "./libs",
        "--include-path",
        "./node_modules",
        "--output-dir",
        out,
    ];

    if config.compiler.optimize {
        let runs: &str = config.compiler.runs.to_string().as_str();
        args.push("--optimize");
        args.push("--optimize-runs");
        args.push(runs);
    }
}
```

// config type using on the function parameter (config templates::Config).

**templates.rs**

```rust
// config templates.
#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub struct Config {
    pub info: ConfigInfo,
    pub compiler: ConfigCompiler,
}

// config.info templates.
#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub struct ConfigInfo {
    pub name: String,
    pub license: String,
}

// config.compiler templates.
#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub struct ConfigCompiler {
    pub solc: String,
    pub optimize: bool,
    pub runs: i64,
}
```

And this is the error I've got when run cargo build.

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> src/solc.rs:58:26
   |
58 |         let runs: &str = config.compiler.runs.to_string().as_str();
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^         - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |                          |
   |                          creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
...
61 |         args.push(runs);
   |                   ---- borrow later used here
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the compiler tell me to consider using a \`let\` binding" when I already am?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28893183/why-does-the-compiler-tell-me-to-consider-using-a-let-binding-when-i-already)

Comment: The value obtained from `config.compiler.runs.to_string()` is not assigned to a variable, so it is dropped prematurely. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28469667/borrowed-value-does-not-live-long-enough-when-using-the-builder-pattern https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37264396/borrowed-value-does-not-live-long-enough-seems-to-blame-the-wrong-thing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47662253/why-is-it-legal-to-borrow-a-temporary

Comment: I asked a concise Question for common rust error `error[E0716]` [error E0716: temporary value dropped while borrowed (rust)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71626083/error-e0716-temporary-value-dropped-while-borrowed-rust). It links back to this Question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You create a new `String` with `to_string`, but don't give it a variable to live in, so it dies at the next `;`. You can solve that by not calling `as_ref` immediately:

```
if config.compiler.optimize {
    let runs: String = config.compiler.runs.to_string();
    // ..
    args.push(runs.as_ref());
}
```

But now you have the next problem: your `args` vector contains string references, but the string in `runs` dies at the end of the `if` block. It must be able to live at least as long as `args`. You can solve this by splitting declaration and assignment for `args`:

```rust
let runs: String;
if config.compiler.optimize {
    runs = config.compiler.runs.to_string();
    // ...
    args.push(runs.as_str());
}
```

Another possibility would be to make `args` a `Vec<String>`.