# 'temporary value dropped while borrowed' when creating Iterator based in condition

Tags: arrays, rust, iterator, conditional-statements

I am trying to build an `Iterator` in Rust that returns the values and indexes of non-null elements in an array. This `Iterator` should be reversible based on a `bool` parameter.

I managed to build the `Iterator` without the *reverse* condition :

```rust
fn main() {
    let arr: [u8; 8] = [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 5];

    for (i, x) in arr.iter().enumerate().filter(|(_, &x)| x!=0) {
        println!("index: {}, value: {}", i, x);
    }
}

>>> index: 1, value: 2
>>> index: 5, value: 1
>>> index: 7, value: 5
```

However, when trying to build an `Iterator` based on a boolean condition (based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29760668/conditionally-iterate-over-one-of-several-possible-iterators)), I get an error when compiling :
*temporary value dropped while borrowed
consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value `rustc(E0716)`*.

```rust
fn main() {
    // Array to observe
    let arr: [u8; 8] = [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 5];
    // Reverse parameter
    let reverse: bool = true;

    // Building Iterator based on `reverse` parameter
    let iter: &mut dyn Iterator<Item = (usize, &u8)> = match reverse {
        // forward Iterator
        false => {
            &mut arr.iter().enumerate().filter(|(_, &x)| x!=0)
        }
        // Reversed iterator
        true => {
            &mut arr.iter().enumerate().filter(|(_, &x)| x!=0).rev()
        }
    };

    // Print indices and values of non 0 elements in the array
    for (i, x) in iter {
        println!("index: {}, value: {}", i, x);
    }
}
```

I have tried cloning the array, or declaring the `Iterator` with the `let` keyword as suggested by the compiler, but none of it seemed to work. Any idea?

Comment: You can solve this by declaring variables to hold the temporaries outside of the `match` statement, same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70847700/401059): [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2968c413ca46b43e7453802d6ee5e71d).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a pretty compact solution using the `Either` crate, inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50204370/16801982).

```rust
extern crate either;
use either::Either;

fn main() {
    // Array to observe
    let arr: [u8; 8] = [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 5];
    // Reverse parameter
    let reverse: bool = true;

    // Pick the right iterator based on reverse
    let iter = match reverse {
        true => Either::Left(arr.iter().enumerate().filter(|(_, &x)| x!=0).rev()),
        false => Either::Right(arr.iter().enumerate().filter(|(_, &x)| x!=0))
    };

    // Print indices and values of non 0 elements in the array
    for (i, x) in iter {
        println!("index: {}, value: {}", i, x);
    }
}

>>> index: 7, value: 5
>>> index: 5, value: 1
>>> index: 1, value: 2
```

This solution solves the problem mentioned by [hkBst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5600363/hkbst) (*types of an `Iterator` and its reverse being different*), as well as the original '*temporary value dropped while borrowed*' compile error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you take a reference to a temporary variable.

While trying to fix it, you will have to work around several other issues to do with iterators, such as that using `rev()` on one changes its type.

I think your code is best written as something like:

```rust
use std::fmt::Display;

fn main() {
    // Array to observe
    let arr: [u8; 8] = [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 5];
    // Reverse parameter
    let reverse: bool = true;

    // Building Iterator
    let iter = arr.iter().enumerate().filter(|(_, &x)| x != 0);

    // Print indices and values of non 0 elements in the array
    if reverse {
        print_iter(iter.rev());
    } else {
        print_iter(iter);
    }
}

fn print_iter<I: Display, T: Display>(iter: impl Iterator<Item = (I, T)>) {
    for (i, x) in iter {
        println!("index: {}, value: {}", i, x);
    }
}
```